# How to get keys from the List of Dictionary

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I have jsondata which is coming in form of  List of Dictionary ..I need to extrct Key and value from each iteration

This is what I have Tried ..

```
var json = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);

JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
List<Dictionary<string,object>> json = serializer.Deserialize<List<Dictionary<string,object>>>(json);

foreach (Dictionary<string, object> record in jsonList )
{
    var imei = record.Keys;
}
```

The above Code return another array of Keys in which I have to select First Element .

This Happens in every Iteration ...I need single Key.Not the Array of Keys

Comment: `record.Keys.First()`?

Comment: Oh yes ..that's The Answer ..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var keys = json.Select(d => d.Keys.First()).ToList();
```

will return first keys from each dictionary